# To determine limit for $f(x,y)$ at origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be continuous function at origin defined by

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin2(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}e^{3x\sin\frac{4}{y}}$$

I tried to evaluate by going to polar coordinates. But how do I deal with exponential term having $\sin$.

Thanks

Comment: $\sin$ is bounded above and below easily. Think about what the $3x\sin(\frac{4}{y})$ ought to converge to and try prove that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\sin 2(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ converges to $2$ at the origin. And $3x\sin\frac{4}{y}$ to zero. Hence $f$ converges to $2$ at the origin.

Comment: To $2$, you mean?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks.

Comment: why does it converges to 0

Comment: Should be $\vert3x\vert$, same conclusion though.

Comment: You have $\left\vert 3x\sin\frac{4}{y} \right\vert \le 3\vert x \vert$ and the limit of the map $(x,y) \mapsto x$ is equal to zero at the origin.